# Ubuntu wireless->wired bridge

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, wireless-networking, bridge

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to connect to a wireless network on my ubuntu 9.10 laptop and have it act as a bridge to a LAN network.

House Wifi router <-> laptop <-> room router <-> NAS/PC

I've found plenty of examples using wired to wired but I'm not finding things for my specific setup.

Wifi House router <-> laptop <-> PC is my immediate goal.  I'm moving out and won't have my USB wifi adapter until a week after I move in:(

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I understand how one makes a eth <-> eth firewall or a router, but not wireless <-> wired.  Perhaps I'm just missing something.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What isn't working? This is a fairly broad question - more detail about what's failing would help us provide better answers

Answer (score 1):

The only differences from doing this with two wired interfaces should be:

- You'll have to make sure that the wireless interface is up first (not such a worry with ethernet interfaces - they tend to come up very early during the boot process)
- The wireless interface will have a different name - ath0 or wi0 or something else - rather than eth0/eth1

You may find that your wireless network is picky about MAC address, in which case a pure bridge might not work - you might have to make your laptop act as a router instead, or have it rewrite MAC addresses, so that the wireless interface only ever sees one MAC address.

([ebtables](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/examples/real.html#example1) can handle the MAC address mangling if that becomes neccessary; it's probably simpler just to set up the routing)